# Can't locate Moo.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, locate, moo

I am trying to run a .pm program in dzsoft perl editor. but i got this error

```
Can't locate Moo.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Users\123\Desktop\ C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at UniNE.pm line 5.
```

My interpertor is ActivePerl-5.18.2.1802-MSWin32-x64-298023
how can I add moo.pm to lib?

Comment: Install it via cpan or ppm. `cpan -i Moo`

Comment: thanks i installed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should install Moo module first. Try from cmd-line: `cpan Moo`

Comment: I have got CPAN installs working in ActiveState, but it often requires a bit of faffing, as you tend to be missing some key elements - such as `make`. It's not impossible to get working, but I'd generally suggest starting with `ppm` which come with ActiveState as a first port of call.

Answer (score 5):

This error means you've got a line that says `use Moo;` and it can't find it. The first question is - have you installed 'Moo'? If not, then:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Moo
```

This may take a bit of faffing with ActivePerl, so you may want to try and use `ppm` instead. If you do definitely have it installed, then I would suggest the next port of call is to try and figure out *where* it ended up - search for `Moo.pm` in your local filesystem, and compare that against your `@INC` path. You may find permissions are the root cause, and it's unreadable by your perl user.

Comment: How can i use ppm to download moo?